# Get previous calculated value in access report

Tags: sql, report, ms-access-2013

I have a report that calculates several results from a table, Is there any way to get the previous value from a calculated camp inside a report?

Let's say I have a Text box A which is inside a "group" in a report, and I need to calculate another result that needs the previous value of A, example:

```
FieldA(1) = TableValue1  FieldB = null(cos FieldA  doesn't have "previous" values") / 54 * 152

FieldA(2) = TableValue2  FieldB = FieldA(1) / 54 * 152
FieldA(3) = TableValue3  FieldB = FieldA(2) / 54 * 152
```

Or is it better to reach this using sql?

Answer (score 1):

This only works in Print Preview mode (i.e. not normal report view mode) but you can use the `Format` event of the section in which the field you are trying to get the previous value for resides.

My table looks like this

[image]

The report looks like

[image]

And that `On Format` event code looks like this

```
Dim prev As String 'A form level variable (not in a sub/function)


Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    txtPrevious = prev
    prev = Me("field1").Value
End Sub
```

It makes a report that looks like this

[image]

Again, it has to be run from Print Preview. Normal Report view does not fire the Format event

[image]

Comment: I think this is what I need, but not sure where to implement the function :S

Comment: @Mark I added another picture of where to put the code. Is that clearer?

Comment: I feel we're really close to do it, but for now it does nothing when  I put the code there. The field from where I need the prev value is ValorA and the field to store it is ValorZ.

Comment: Does the code run? If you put a break point in the format even does it get hit at all? It will get skipped when not in Print Preview.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using this report inside a form, so de preview does'nt work :( myabe I'm doint it wrong from the begining

Comment: Unfortunately that's just not going to work (as far as I know). There is the Paint event which will fire at the time you want buuuut it will fire infinitely because it is setting the value of a control then because that control was set it paints itself again. Is there a way for you to know the previous record based on the current record? Alex's answer might help you out more there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would be: implement a time series Tables on any specific fields that require to trace the historic values. For example, assuming you have an '`Employees`' data Table with a '`Salary`' field. In this case, new value overrides the previously entered one. In order to resolve this issue and be able to trace the historic values, create a second Table `Salary` linked to the main Table "Employees" on the primary id fields, add 'Salary' field and a `TimeStamp` field, so you will be able to trace the Employee's salary history.

Your Report will be based on the `Join` between two Table, thus you would be able to display the current (latest) and previous values sorted on `TimeStamp` in descending order.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Updated the example, sorry it was my fault explaining my problem.

Comment: @Mark, it gives a completely new meaning to your question: now it seems like A and B corresponds to different rows of the same table and you are trying to calculate the difference between rows. Would you please post a sample data in report and underlying table, and your SQL code snippet (otherwise, it will be just another round of guessing for us)? Thanks and regards,

Comment: I need to calculate some % and to reach this I need the previous calculated result. My question is if this is possible in an access report? Sorry for my poor explanation. But the sql query is a simple select and the results are calculated/displayed in a report.

Comment: OK, then it's a different scenario. I guess, folks already gave you an answer. Best Regards,